# If $A=B-C$ then $B=A\cup C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried to prove this by showing that A+C=B, which I think is valid? As in A+C=B is equivalent to A=B-C. Then B isn't the same as $A\cup C$, because A+C could give you $A\cap B$ twice if they have elements in the intersect. At least this is houw I reason about it.

Comment: The statement is not true. Let $B=\{1,2\}$ and $C=\{2,3\}$. Then $A=B\setminus C=\{1\}$ but $A\cup C=\{1,2,3\}$ whereas $|B|=2$.

Answer (score 1):

As shown by @TheSimpliFire the result is, in general, false. It is only true if $C$ is a subset of $B$.

A correct general statement is $B=A\cup (B\cap C).$

*Proof*

$$B=(B\cap C')\cup(B\cap C)=(B-C)\cup(B\cap C)=A\cup(B\cap C).$$

Answer (score 0):

From the hypothesis , that is A = B - C, one can prove that B is included in A U C . The reverse inclusion would still have to be shown, if possible.

ERRATUM : at line (16) read " by definition of " inclusion" ( and not " by definition of union ")

[image]